# How to count consecutive repetitions of a substring in a string?

Tags: python, string

I need to find consecutive (non-overlapping) repetitions of a substring in a string. I can count them but not consecutive. For instance:

```
string = "AASDASDDAAAAAAAAERQREQREQRAAAAREWQRWERAAA"
substring = "AA"
```

here, `"AA"` is repeated one time at the beginning of the string, then 4 times, then 2 times, etc.
I should select the biggest one, in this example - 4 times.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I used count(), but it didn't resolve the problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) shine when searching through strings. Here you can find all groups of one or more `AA` with `(?:AA)+` the `(?:` simply tells the engine to interpret the parentheses for grouping only.

Once you have the groups you can use `max()` to find the longest based on length (`len()`).

```
import re

s = "AASDASDDAAAAAAAAERQREQREQRAAAAREWQRWERAAA"

groups = re.findall(r'(?:AA)+', s)
print(groups)
# ['AA', 'AAAAAAAA', 'AAAA', 'AA']

largest = max(groups, key=len)
print(len(largest) // 2)
# 4
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! it's a great way to solve it, i don't know much about regex, so i need to learn about it.!

Comment: I thought `r'(AA)+'` would work as well, but it didn't.

Answer (score 8):

one way to do it with basic operations is to search for the pattern "AA" in the string and add "AA" to the search until you don't find any more:

```
string  = "AASDASDDAAAAAAAAERQREQREQRAAAAREWQRWERAAA"
count   = 0
pattern = "AA"
while pattern in string:
    count += 1
    pattern += "AA"
```

output:

```
print(count) # 4
```

It could also be written on a single line like this:

```
count = next(r-1 for r in range(1,len(string)+1) if "AA"*r not in string)
```

You could also use the `find()` method instead of the `in` operator which would allow the search to continue from the first match instead of starting over from the beginning of the string:

```
string  = "AASDASDDAAAAAAAAERQREQREQRAAAAREWQRWERAAA"
pattern = "AA"

repeated = ""
position = 0
while position >= 0:
    repeated += pattern
    position = string.find(repeated,position)
count = len(repeated)//len(pattern)-1  
        
print(count) # 4
```

Comment: your first solution is literally underestimated

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This simply iterates through the words and updates the max on each iteration.

```
string = "AASDASDDAAAAAAAAAERQREQREQRAAAAREWQRWERAAA" #normal case
#string_2 = "BAASDAAAAAAAAERQREQREQRAAAAREWQRWERAAA" #edge case

substring = "AA"
max_count=0
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(string),len(substring)):
    print(string[i-len(substring):i])
    if string[i-1:i] == substring[:1] and count == 0:
        i = i+(len(substring)-1)
    if string[i-len(substring):i] == substring:
        count+= 1
    else:
        count = 0
    max_count = max(max_count,count)

print(max_count)
```

outputs

```
4
```

Since you are new, try using a [visualizer](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to get a better understanding of the code execution.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it fails when the pairs don't line up evenly. `string = "BAASDAAAAAAAAERQREQREQRAAAAREWQRWERAAA"` Result = 3?

Comment: As mark mentioned, this will give a wrong value for the example in the comments. If you want to run it for that let me know i will write code to handle to edge case values

Comment: I don’t have a way of checking right now, does the code work with substring = “AAA”?

Comment: It didn't at first, mainly because this fails in the edge cases. My new update works perfectly now. It does look a bit intricate, so I would simply prefer the solution by @Mark meyer. A side note: it's always good to state the problem before downvoting it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "AASDASDDAAAAAAAAERQREQREQRAAAAREWQRWERAAA"
substring = "AA"
count = 0
string_length = len(string)
substring_length = len(substring)
for i in range( round( string_length / substring_length ) ):
    if (i * substring) in string:
        count = i
return count
```