# Function to count consecutive strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

```
def DNAalg(STR, seq):
    count = 0
    maximum = 0


    for i in range(len(seq)):
        if seq[i:i+len(STR)] == STR:


            for k in range(i, len(seq), len(STR)):
                if seq[k:k+len(STR)] == STR:
                    count += 1
                
                else:
                    if count>maximum:
                        maximum = int(count)
                        count = 0
                    break

    return maximum

seq = "GCTAAATTTGTTCAGCCAGATGTAGGCTTACAAATCAAGCTGTCCG...... many more letters"
STR = "AGATC"
print(DNAalg(STR,seq))
```

I would like to find the maximum occurences of a consecutive string(STR) in a long string(seq).

I tried with my code to iterate through until i encounter such a string, and from there do another loop with steps of the lenght of the string to look for more and count up until i do not encounter another one. I do not see any flaws in my logic. Any help is appreciated in solving that problem, either with my code or alternatives.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in the question.

Comment: copy paste didnt work properly, i fixed the indentation.

Comment: If you did not see any flaws in your logic, what led you to creating this post?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count consecutive substring in a string in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131768/how-to-count-consecutive-substring-in-a-string-in-python-3)

Comment: The code is not working and I do not see why. That is the reason i created that post.

Comment: @Axiumin_ In part, but i prefer not to use the regular expressions library.

Comment: Can you please provide desired result so we understand what you are asking for. Are you trying to find the max length of a substring between two groups of `AGATC`. For example, if the string is `GCTAAATTTAGATCTTCCGTCTAGATC`, then the length will be 8 as this value  `TTCCGTCT` is between two `AGATC`

Comment: Example. Str1 = 'TC'  Str2 = 'ABTCTCOPOPTCTCTCTCLMTCLMTCTCTC'. As one can see the longest consecutive occurance of TC is TCTCTCTC. My question was, how to find the number of longest consecutive Str1 in Str2 ? In this case it is 4.

Answer (score 0):

The break statement drops me out of the loop without resetting the count back to 0. That was the flaw in the code. Thanks for the help.

```
             else:
                if count>maximum:
                    maximum = int(count)
                    count = 0
                else:
                    count = 0
                break
```