# How do I compare two panda dictionaries to output the match? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

Short tl/dr: I am writing a program that will take a sequence of DNA (1 line txt file) and a CSV file containing STR counts for a list of individuals and then output to whom the DNA (most likely) belongs. I converted both the CSV file and the STR counts into pandas tables, but I am at the last step of just comparing the data to find the match.

Detailed Question: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/dna/
(its from the official harvard course site, enough for me to believe it will be virus free, but its up to you to check it out yourself if you want)

The two source files needed including files to test your code: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/dna/

Here's my code:

```
from sys import argv
import cs50
import csv
import re
import pandas

# using https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/reading-csv-files to understand how to read the csv files

if len(argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
    exit(1)

with open(argv[1]) as f:

    db = pandas.read_csv(f"{argv[1]}",converters={"AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG":int})

with open(argv[2]) as s:
    k = s.readline()

# have to find AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG
dna = (k)

AGATC = 0
TTTTTTCT = 0
AATG = 0
TCTAG = 0
GATA = 0
TATC = 0
GAAA = 0
TCTG = 0

# help taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131768/how-to-count-consecutive-substring-in-a-string-in-python-3
# yes i know i couldve iterated, just avoid this
pattern_AGATC = "AGATC"
while pattern_AGATC in dna:
    AGATC += 1
    pattern_AGATC += "AGATC"

pattern_TTTTTTCT = "TTTTTTCT"
while pattern_TTTTTTCT in dna:
    TTTTTTCT += 1
    pattern_TTTTTTCT += "TTTTTTCT"

pattern_AATG = "AATG"
while pattern_AATG in dna:
    AATG += 1
    pattern_AATG += "AATG"

pattern_TCTAG = "TCTAG"
while pattern_TCTAG in dna:
    TCTAG += 1
    pattern_TCTAG += "TCTAG"

pattern_GATA = "GATA"
while pattern_GATA in dna:
    GATA += 1
    pattern_GATA += "GATA"

pattern_TATC = "TATC"
while pattern_TATC in dna:
    TATC += 1
    pattern_TATC += "TATC"

pattern_GAAA = "GAAA"
while pattern_GAAA in dna:
    GAAA += 1
    pattern_GAAA += "GAAA"

pattern_TCTG = "TCTG"
while pattern_TCTG in dna:
    TCTG += 1
    pattern_TCTG += "TCTG"

# building a dict for the STRs
dict_STRs = dict({'AGATC': AGATC, 'TTTTTTCT': TTTTTTCT, 'AATG': AATG, 'TCTAG': TCTAG, 'GATA': GATA, 'TATC': TATC, 'GAAA': GAAA, 'TCTG': TCTG})

# learnt pandas through https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html
strs = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_STRs, orient='index', columns=['Counts'])

# I know i could use db.iloc[0,1] and strs.iloc[0,0] to compare, but my code doesnt work
# I am stuck down here, if someone could finish or guide this last step it would be great
IndexNoOfMatch = 0
for i in db:
    for j in db:
        for k in db:
            for l in db:
                # using try to avoid string (the names), any advice?
                try:
                    if db.iloc[i, j] == strs.iloc[k, l]:
                        IndexNoOfMatch = i
                # no idea what except does, using it as it connects try apparently
                except:
                    if db.iloc[i, j] == strs.iloc[k, l]:
                        IndexNoOfMatch = i
print(IndexNoOfMatch)
```

(Yes I understand there would be a 100% better way to write and design my code but I spent days on this and only stuck at the last step)

Better way to understand what I am saying ->
Need to output 'Bob' as the answer as his DNA matches according to the two pandas dictionaries

The database:

```
 name  AGATC  AATG  TATC
0    Alice      2     8     3
1      Bob      4     1     5
2  Charlie      3     2     5
```

The sample DNA counts:

```
          Counts
AGATC          4
TTTTTTCT       0
AATG           1
TCTAG          0
GATA           1
TATC           5
GAAA           1
TCTG           0
```

I only have a 3 day deadline so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Perhaps you can find a solution in [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dpsets%2F6%2Fdna)